# Set 1st image of old published posts as featured image

Tags: sql, image, wordpress

I am moving my WordPress website to a new theme and the new theme uses featured images where as old one didnt hence my old posts dont have any featured images. Now there are over 3000 posts in my website and obviously setting featured images for them manually is kind of impossible.

So can you guys help me make an SQL query or link me to some plugin which can do this?

There are a few requirements if these can be fulfilled easily. First of all, I want the first image of the post to be set as featured not the first 'attached' images. Secondly, the query or plugin shouldnt do anything to posts which already have featured images.

Thanks,

Comment: Check https://gist.github.com/brajeshwar/1205901

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did the previous theme call the featured image?
Most themes these days include the add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' )

You'll want to look into this:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails

To post the actual Featured Image inside the post, you'll want to look into this.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail

If you're looking to post a featured image at the top of the content, try this.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content

I have not tested this but something like this might work.

```
function my_the_content_filter( $content ) {
 if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
   $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');
   echo '<a href="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" >';
   the_post_thumbnail('large');
   echo '</a>';
   // Returns the content.
   return $content;
 }
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter', 10 );
```

Comment: Actually my old theme wasnt using featured images but the new one does. And all the needed calls are already in place. The actual issue is that since old posts dont have any featured images attached to them, these posts look odd on the new theme. So I need a function or query which can add first image of all old posts as featured images so that everything looks pretty.

Comment: Then try the above solution and adjust the large to thumbnail, medium, or large. If you're looking for a custom size, you'll need to add add_image_size().